# Get all lproj folders in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How can I get all lproj folders created previously? I need to know how many languages are been created in Xcode project to offer to the user the option to force another Language in the iOS App

Comment: This isn't related to the `xcode IDE` so why have you used that tag??

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Is the most appropiate?

```
NSArray *dirFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]error:nil];
NSArray *lprojFiles = [dirFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.lproj'"]];
```